# DataTable is not showing only return json format?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, datatable

I have a logic and want it to display dataTable, currently its showing json format and need some help to fix this issue. I will attach below the screen shot of the result, i want to know reason as to why its returning that format not DataTable?[image]

```
//GET:Data-Using-DataTable.
        public ActionResult GeteNtsaDataResults()
        {
            using (eNtsaRegistration_2 model = new eNtsaRegistration_2())
            {
                List<eNtsaRegPeopleList> eNtsaRegs = cb.RegPeopleLists.ToList<eNtsaRegPeopleList>();
                return Json(new { data = eNtsaRegs }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "People_Lists";
}

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {    
        $('#dataTable').DataTable({    
            "ajax": {    
                "url": "/Home/GeteNtsaDataResults",    
                "type": "GET",    
                "datatype": "json"  ,  
                 "dataSrc": ""  
  
            },    
            "columns": [    
                { "data": "LoginID" },    
                { "data": "Name" },    
                { "data": "SSID" },    
                { "data": "Section" },    
                { "data": "Role" },    
                { "data": "LastActivity" },    
                { "data": "TotalActivity" }    
            ]    
        });    
    }); 

</script>

<div class="container py-4">
    <h4 class="text-center text-uppercase"></h4>
    <div id="dataTable_wrapper"></div>
    <table id="dataTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>LoginID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>SSID</th>
                <th>Section</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>LastActivity</th>
                <th>TotalActivity</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sujit thanks let me work on it on this example, i might miss few things. then i will shout if im stuck for those changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this example.
-> https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/data_rendering.html

Remove "tbody" tag from HTML. Also add relevant css for data table.